# Rakefiles: variable scope available in `load`ed scripts

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

In my `~/Sites/` directory I have the omnipotent Rakefile:

```
desc "Run deliver in each directory"
task :deliver do
  sh 'for a in $(ls ./*/Rakefile); do (cd $(dirname $a); rake -f Rakefile deliver); done'
end
```

(Along with other fun production tasks, and the stupid "default" task that lists all tasks [see https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/22])

Some directories inside `Sites` have a Rakefile in them. Most look like this:

```
# Rsync options
production_server = 'pacificmedicaltraining.net'
production_user = 'training2'
production_www_dir = 'www'
local_www_dir = 'www'
local_git_dir = 'git'

desc "Run all build and deployment tasks, for continuous delivery"
task :deliver => [:pullgit, :buildjekyll, :pushproduction]

desc "Bring deployed server files local"
task :pullgit do
  puts 'Pulling git'
  sh "cd '#{local_git_dir}'; git pull"
  puts 'Pulled'
end

...
```

The behavior of this Rakefile is defined fully by the options at the top and the `deliver` task (other sites might not use Jekyll for building). All remaining tasks in this file are copy-paste. In the interest of DRY, I have removed the copy-pasted tasks into `~/Sites/common.rake` and included this file with `load '../common.rake'` in the contributing files.

> Pulling git
>   rake aborted!
>   NameError: undefined local variable or method 'local_git_dir' for main:Object
>   /Users/williamentriken/Sites/common.rake:4:in 'block in '
>   Tasks: TOP => pullgit
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

How do I make that variable available to the `load`ed script?

Comment: Where do you call `load`?

Comment: first thing in that file

Answer (score -1):

> How do I make that variable available to the `load`ed script?

You can't. It's a local variable. Local variables are local to the scope they are defined in, they don't exist in other scopes. That's why they are called local variables.